# What is the Correct Syntax of Variable as Column?

Tags: vba, excel

VBA will let me do this:

```
Columns("A:A").Select
```

But I need to do this:

```
Columns("ColNumToLet:ColNumToLet").Select
```

where ColNumToLet is a variable of type variant and has a value of A. VBA throws a Type mismatch error. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: The error arises from inappropriate use of `"`, which means that you are passing a literal string.  You've got two suitable answers, below. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to convert to letters:

```
 Columns(ColNum).Select
```

If you need to use letters then

```
 Columns(ColNumToLet).Select
```

will also work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to use letters to define a span of columns:

```
Sub marine()
    alpha = "A"
    omega = "O"
    Columns(alpha & ":" & omega).Select
End Sub
```